# Owl Carousel Problem - Content jumps up and down

Tags: jquery, wordpress, carousel, owl-carousel

I have an Owl carousel, and its wired up quite complicatedly.

https://www.iga.com.au/recipes/chocolate-lovers-cake/

On this page, please click the red "Make it now" button, and then keep pressing the next button. You can see that the content jumps all over the page, and the transition is not smooth. You can also get the same problem while swiping left and right.

If we "Next", "Next" into a few items, and then press the cross icon (top left) the content scrolls back to the first slide, but again it loses its position, and jumps all over the place

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I have looked all over for a solution.

Comment: So you need to define min-height of `Owl-Carousel` div.

Comment: Hi @RaeeshAlam, I tried doing that, but I can't find a parameter in the Owl Carousel documentation, and I tried forcing it through CSS but it doesn't seem to work - please take a look at this page again, and the div with the ID #guidedCooking (which also has the class owl-carousel) has the min-height set as 500px